# Nuclear fusion in Chadwick’s experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fusion

I got confused when I was researching about “neutron’s discovery in Chadwick’s experiment”. There was a nuclear equation said that when we bombard the alpha particles into beryllium, it will emits neutron particles as shown in this equation
$$\rm {^9Be} + \alpha(^4He) \to {^{12}C} + {^1n}$$
What I am confused about is, isn’t the equation above a nuclear fusion reaction? As far as I know, nuclear fusion reactions require really high energy like on the Sun, but this experiment happens in a laboratory. So I wonder if nuclear fusion reactions can happen in laboratory, why can’t we use it to produce clean energy?

Comment: "why can’t we use it to produce clean energy?" [Not enough yield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_energy_gain_factor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to achieve fusion reactions in a laboratory. To this end, one can use, for example, accelerators or [fusors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor). What is extremely difficult is achieving net energy gain.

Answer (score 2):

$\alpha$ particles, as emitted by radioactive nuclei, actually
do have a quite high kinetic energy, typically around
$5$ MeV (see [Wikipedia - Alpha particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_particle)).
This energy corresponds to a temperature of $6\cdot 10^{10}$ K,
if you would want to produce such $\alpha$ particles just by
heating helium gas.